# kamailio add trunk with credentials

Tags: kamailio

recently started with kamailio and looks really good. i have a few extensions and they are talking to each other through rtp proxy. Easy stuff.

the tricky bit is to add a provider to talk to the outside world. all the documentation that i have seen is about unauthenticated gateway. In my case i have a sip provider (voip.whatever.com) and has username/passwd(atux/mypasswd). i have tested this trunk in an asterisk and it works fine. the question how do i make it work in kamailio, please?

Answer (score 1):

For authentication to a remote server that should be done by Kamailio, look at **uac** module, the **uac_auth()** function:

- https://www.kamailio.org/docs/modules/stable/modules/uac.html#uac.f.uac_auth

Note that if the gateway is doing CSeq value checking, then you have to add **dialog** module and enable CSeq tracking feature.